# Print group of data if contain specific word

Tags: python

I have input file which contains data as

```
cell ANC
input A1 ;
input A2 ;
output Z ;
Type combinational
func  ((A1 A2))
cell BPX
input A1 ;
input B ;
output ZN ;
Type sequential 
func  ((A1+B))
```

I want my output as

```
cell ANC
input A1 ;
input A2 ;
output Z ;
Type combinational
func  ((A1 A2))
```

I.e the cell which contains `Type combinational` should be printed.
I tried the code

```
copy1 = False
with open("out","w") as o:
   with open("in","r") as i:
      for line in i:
        if line.startswith(("cell")):
           if "Type combinational " in line:
               copy1 = True
           print >> o,line
```

But I am getting output only cell line

```
cell ANC
cell BPX
```

Comment: The logic seems do do what you ask. Which is to unconditionally print any line starting with "cell" to out. One of the problems you are running into is that you are not reading cells at a time, you are reading lines at a time. The incomplete solution provided by Serial Lazer should help you underway towards a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Minor mods required in your function, since you need to print the block of lines corresponding to the cells:

```
with open("out","w") as o:
   with open("in","r") as i:
      lines_str = ""
      print_block = False
      for line in i:
        if line.startswith("cell"):
          if print_block:
            print >> o, lines_str
          lines_str = line
        elif line.startswith("Type combinational"):
          print_block = True
          lines_str += line
        else:
          lines_str += line
```

Output:

```
cell ANC
input A1 ;
input A2 ;
output Z ;
Type combinational
func  ((A1 A2))
```

Comment: How can I see out in file containing only cell having Type combinational? I am doing print, But not getting

Comment: The above code works fine for me and only outputs the cells with "type combinational". Which version of python are you using?

Comment: i am using Python 2.7.5

Comment: And whats the error you are getting when you run the above code?

Comment: I am getting both type combinational and type sequential dispalyed. I.e getting back the input data only

Comment: Well, thats not possible; I tested on your own input-file and works well. Please pass on a screenshot of the output

Comment: Sir, can u check if ```lines_str = line``` is just below the ```print >> o, lines_str``` or there is backspace as shown above. Because I am getting ```syntax error``` cursor pointing to ```elif```